# Android bundle from pending intent always recieved as null

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, android-pendingintent

I tried everything suggested in stackOverflow - nothing helps.
The notification works fine, it's just loses it's bundle somehow.

here is my PendingIntent:

```
 NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
         //   Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, LoginActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(Constants.KEY_BUNDLE_MESSAGE_FROM_NOTIFICATION,true);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);


            //intent.setAction("dummy");

            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            NotificationCompat.Builder noBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(text)
/*                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(message))*/
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentIntent(contentIntent);

            notificationManager.notify(0, noBuilder.build());
```

1) adding action to the Intent: intent.setAction("dummy");

2) adding setClass to the Intent: .setClass(this, LoginActivity.class);

3) Pending intent tried all flags: PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT / FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT / FLAG_ONE_SHOT/ 0

4) tried recieving the extras in both "onNewIntent" and in "onCreate"

the extras in the recieving activity is always false

```
 @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        Log.d(TAG, "im in login from notification!   "+ intent.hasExtra(Constants.KEY_BUNDLE_MESSAGE_FROM_NOTIFICATION));
    }


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Log.d(TAG, "im in login from notification!   "+ intent.hasExtra(Constants.KEY_BUNDLE_MESSAGE_FROM_NOTIFICATION));
```

}

any ideas? 
Thanks!

Comment: In `onNewIntent` add : `setIntent(intent)`

Comment: still got false in the logs as always..

Comment: your code all looks fine. Please post the manifest

Answer (score 0):

In `onNewIntent` add : `setIntent(intent)`